# Python Selenium issue with submit button, not working consistently

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to build a web scraper for redfin to pull the redfin estimate. I have a function that does this and sometimes it works and sometimes it does not work. I noticed that the reason it does not work is because of the submit function. Sometimes the chrome page wont press the search (submit) button and go to the property page.

I am not sure how to fix this issue and make it more consistent.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.remote import webelement
import pandas as pd
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.redfin.com/')
time.sleep(3)

def get_redfin_estimate(address):
    search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('searchInputBox')
    search_box.send_keys(address)
    search_box.submit()
    time.sleep(3)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    try:
        price1 = soup.find('div', {'class', 'avm'}).div.text
        return(price1)
    except AttributeError:
        try:
            time.sleep(10)
            price2 = soup.find('span',class_='avmLabel').find_next('span', class_='value').text
            return(price2)
        except:
            return('N/A')


print(get_redfin_estimate('687 Catalina Laguna Beach, CA 92651'))
print(get_redfin_estimate('693 Bluebird Canyon Drive, Laguna Beach, CA 92651'))



driver.quit()
```

Comment: Have you tried not using `.submit()` and actually clicking on the magnifying glass element to submit the search?

Comment: @JeffC I am totally new to this stuff, if you have an answer please provide one.

Comment: Delete the `search_box.submit()` line, find the element by the CSS selector `button[title='Search']`, and click it.

Comment: @JeffC I am sure how to do that can you provide the line I need to replace for search_box.submit() please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be an issue with using `.submit()` on that element. One alternative is to just click on the magnifying glass to initiate the search.

```
def get_redfin_estimate(address):
    driver.find_element_by_name('searchInputBox').send_keys(address)
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[title='Search']").click()
    time.sleep(3)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    ... and so on
```

Comment: driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button[title='Search']').click()
                                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Sorry, fixed typo

Comment: You didn't get the final update. I hit save too quickly and only changed one typo. You really need to spend some time reading some python tutorials so you can fix these basic items on your own. It was just a case of mismatched quotes.

Comment: Yea I know I was asked to build this at work and I normally do research in ML and use C++ to write algorithms so I am totally new to this

Answer (score 1):

The reason **submit** button is not working consistently because the desired element is a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element and the *Locator Strategy* you have used doesn't identifies the **search box** with *placeholder* as **City, Address, School, Agent, ZIP** uniquely and identifies 3 elements.

To send a *character sequence* to the desired field you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  def get_redfin_estimate(address):
      WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.searchInputNode input.search-input-box#search-box-input"))).send_keys(address)
      driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.searchInputNode button.inline-block.SearchButton.clickable").click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  def get_redfin_estimate(address):
      WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='searchInputNode']//input[@class='search-input-box' and @id='search-box-input']"))).send_keys(address)
      driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='searchInputNode']//button[@class='inline-block SearchButton clickable float-right']").click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thank you, could you update the code I have in your answer?

Comment: @Wolfy I didn't get you. How can I help you?

Comment: I understand your answer, but could you update to include my code with the appropriate changes that you suggested?

Comment: Does that make sense? I just want to make sure my code is perfectly corrected given the changes you suggested...

Comment: @Wolfy Check out the answer update and let me know if you have got the expected answer.

Comment: Sorry I will try to be more clear. Can you copy and paste my code from the question and make the appropriate changes that you suggested in my code? I hope that is more clear

Comment: @Wolfy No, the answers job is not to copy/paste the entirety of your code, it is to answer your question. The code here should be enough for you to see what the differences are and move that into your code on your own. You are already getting free advice... why can't you move the suggested code into your own by yourself?

Comment: @JeffC Given the answers he provided with the changes that I made I still get the same problem. I.e. sometimes it works and sometimes it does not...

Comment: That's because his answer isn't really any different than what you already had. Your locator actually finds three elements but the first is the one you wanted so that doesn't matter. He just (over) specified the first element with a locator that uniquely finds the first element... but it doesn't change what actually happens.

Comment: @Wolfy Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.